# What is a make at home alternative for mocha mix dairy free ice cream?

Tags: dairy-substitutes, dairy-products

What is a make at home alternative for mocha mix dairy free ice cream?

In the 1990s, there existed a dairy free ice-cream known as "**mocha mix**".

[image: picture of mocha mix]

**Mocha mix** had no mocha in it, and was ***not*** coffee related.

Is there a vegan ice cream recipe which contains a lot of partially hydrogenated soybean oil?

The original mocha mix ingredients were as follows, but only the first 4 or 5 ingredients are useful for making homemade vegan ice cream.

> Water, Sugar, Corn Syrup, Partially Hydrogenated Soybean Oil, Modified Food Starch, Maltodextrin, Soy Protein, Dipotassium Phosphate, Natural and Artificial Flavor, Mono & Diglycerides, Monoglycerides, Sodium Stearoyl Lactylate, Microcrystalline Cellulose, Cellulose Gum, Diacetyl Tartaric Acid Ester of Mono & Diglycerides, Guar Gum, Polysorbate 65, Xanthan Gum, Calcium Sulfate, Polysorbate 60, Dextrose, Artificial Color (Annatto), Carrageenan, Polysorbate 80.

Comment: I wonder if the name referred to Japanese mochi rather than choccy coffeey beverages? https://tastesbetterfromscratch.com/mochi-ice-cream/